# Subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}/20\mathbf{Z}$ using Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> According to Lagrange's Theorem, what are the possible sizes of the subgroups of  $\mathbf{Z}/20\mathbf{Z}$?

I have no idea how to go about answering this. I have a feeling that I should be breaking $20 $into products of primes, but that really is a stab in the dark.

> $|H| ≤ 20$
>
> $|H| | |S20| = 20!$

This is as far as I have got and I have literally no idea on what is going on.

Comment: $|Z_{20}| = 20$, and by Lagrange's theorem, any subgroup must divide the order of the group that it is a subgroup of. What numbers divide 20?

Comment: 20 can be divided by 10, 5, 4 and 2? No idea what I am doing with these guys though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrange's theorem says for a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ we have $\# G=[G:H]\# H$ (here $\# G$ denotes the order of $G$, the "number of elements of $G$"); in particular, *if $G$ is finite then $\# H$ divides $\# G$*. In our case $G=\mathbf{Z}/20\mathbf{Z}$ has $\# G=20$ (you should know this), namely $\bar{0},\ldots,\bar{19}$. So a subset $H$ of $G$ can only be a subgroup if $\# H$ divides 20, so only if $\# H$ is either $20,10,5,4,2,1$. That for every such number (divisor of $20$) we have a subgroup of that order *is not asserted by Lagrange's theorem*, but is in our case [true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups).

Comment: The condition is necessary but not sufficient. You would still need to show that there is a subgroup of that size - e.g. there is no order 30 subgroup of $A_5$. (Although from the way the question is phrased, I'm not sure that's required).

Comment: Of course not, @Mathmo123 you are pointing out the obvious. The standard counter example is $A_4$.

Comment: obvious to you I'm sure - but still worth pointing out in case future readers don't realise that

Comment: I have about zero mathematical capabilities. If you could dumb it down for me, it would be greatly appreciated. I literally haven't a clue what I am doing.

Comment: @RoySheehan: are you happy now?

Comment: @BlindSchleiche I actually think I can understand it. Thanks so much for your help; really appreciate it!